# Difference between enterAlwaysCollapsed and exitUntilCollapsed scroll flags in coordinate layout

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm unable to understand difference between these two scroll flags applied to the toolbar or collapsing toolbar, when scroll up and scroll down

Answer (score 24):

Update:

if you are still confused read the following blog:
https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02

---

Old:

**1. enterAlways:** The view will become visible when scrolling up. This flag is useful in cases when scrolling from the bottom of a list and wanting to expose the Toolbar as soon as scrolling up takes place.

[image]

Normally, the Toolbar only appears when the list is scrolled to the top as shown below:

[image]

**2. enterAlwaysCollapsed:** Normally, when only *enterAlways* is used, the Toolbar will continue to expand as you scroll down:
[image]

Assuming **enterAlways** is declared and you have specified a **minHeight**, you can also specify **enterAlwaysCollapsed**. When this setting is used, your view will only appear at this minimum height. Only when scrolling reaches to the top will the view expand to its full height:

[image]

**3. exitUntilCollapsed:** When the ***scroll*** flag is set, scrolling down will normally cause the entire content to move:

[image]

Read more: https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02

Comment: still unable to understand

Comment: tell me in manner like what happens when we up and down scroll in both views and what is the difference in comparative table

Comment: https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02

Answer (score 10):

In case somebody's searching, I've made the description of all flags:

### **scroll**

***Scroll Up***: the view becomes visible when the layout's been scrolled all the way up 
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the content like it's a part of it; will hide if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **enterAlways**

**Scroll Up**: the view becomes visible on every scroll up action, even if there's still a lot of content to scroll up
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the content like it's a part of it; will hide if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **enterAlwaysCollapsed**

**Scroll Up**: the collapsed version of the view (e.g. `Toolbar`) becomes visible on every scroll up action, and it expands (e.g. `Toolbar` with an `ImageView`) only when scrolled all the way up
**Scroll Down**: the view collapses and then hides, if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **exitUntilCollapsed**

**Scroll Up**: the view is always visible, provided its height is > 0 and the expanded version (e.g. Toolbar with an ImageView) will become visible when scrolled all the way up 
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the layout's content, but only till its collapsed state (hence - *"exit until collapsed"*), so in case of a `Toolbar` with a fixed height, it will always be visible on the top

### **snap**

**Scroll Up AND Down** fast scrolls up or down based on how much of the view is visible - if more than 50% - the view will scroll down, showing itself, if less - the view will hide; used with other flags as a further customization

Check out my [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout_scrollflags/) with an example code on [GitHub](https://github.com/lomza/AppBar-ScrollFlags-Example)